# problem with date()

Tags: php

I am using the date() function to display a timestamp from my databse.

```
$date = date( 'F jS', $news_items['date']);
```

I know the `$news_items['date'];` as they return in a YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00 format.

But after the function call `$date` dispays as December 31st for all values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$date = date('F jS', strtotime($news_items['date']));
```

Try that :)

Answer (score 3):

That's because date() wants a timestamp and not a string. You're better of with something like this;

```
$dt   = date_create($news_items['date']);
$date = date_format($dt, 'F jS');
```

Or in the object oriented way;

```
$dt   = new DateTime($news_items['date']);
$date = $dt->format('F jS');
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax for date function is given in PHP manual as:

```
string date  ( string $format  [, int $timestamp  ] )
```

As you can see the second argument is expected to be an integer, but you are feeding the function with a string.